# Netsuite custom formula field

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom item field in a form for entering a date, then I wanted to create another custom item field of free/text type for displaying the month name depending on the entered date based on a formula, however I can't make any operation  with the custom date field without getting an error of invalid expression, even if I just set the formula to reference the date field it returns me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `trim(to_char({custitemX}, 'MONTH'))` ?

The functions available for formula fields and columns use PL/SQL functions.

see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510 for TO_CHAR